# Error in invoking target 'links proc gen_pcscfg' of makefile oracle error in ubuntu

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, makefile, ubuntu-15.04

I am using Ubuntu 15.04, I am trying to install Oracle 11G.
before installing the Oracle I have install all the package mention bellow.

```html
sudo apt-get install libaio1
sudo apt-get install libaio-dev
sudo apt-get install unixODBC
sudo apt-get install unixODBC-dev
sudo apt-get install expat
sudo apt-get install sysstat
sudo apt-get install libelf-dev
sudo apt-get install elfutils
sudo apt-get install lsb-cxx
sudo apt-get install pdksh
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
sudo apt-get install ksh
sudo apt-get install lesstif2
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install gawk
sudo apt-get install binutils
sudo apt-get install gawk
sudo apt-get install x11-utils
sudo apt-get install rpm
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo apt-get install lsb-rpm
sudo apt-get install libmotif3
sudo apt-get install lesstif2
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

While installing Oracle I am getting this error
[image: Error]

**LOG Errors**

```html
INFO: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib64/libpthread_nonshared.a inside 

INFO: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

INFO: /home/varun/app/varun/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/plsql/lib/ins_plsql.mk:33: recipe for target 'wrap' failed

INFO: make: *** [wrap] Error 1

INFO: End output from spawned process.
INFO: ----------------------------------
INFO: Exception thrown from action: make
Exception Name: MakefileException
Exception String: Error in invoking target 'install' of makefile '/home/varun/app/varun/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/plsql/lib/ins_plsql.mk'. See '/home/varun/app/oraInventory/logs/installActions2015-08-27_11-31-03PM.log' for details.
Exception Severity: 1
```

I really dont have idea how do I resolve this. Searched lot on the net but could not find solution. Does any body have idea how do I FIXED IT

Answer (score 0):

This is an unsupported linux release for oracle 11g. You are pretty much on your own to get this to work. Otherwise check the oracle linux installation guide for supported linux versions and distributions (they are generally redhat based).